# What are Interval Regular Expression and Tagged Regular Expression?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I was recently reading about sed when I encountered this topic. I need examples to understand the topic better.

Answer (score 5):

The interval regular expression operator in *Basic Regular Expressions* (BRE) as supported by standard `sed` would refer to `\{x,y\}`.

The equivalent ERE (extended) or PCRE (`perl` compatible) operators (with `-r/-E`, `-R`/`-P` with some `sed` implementations) would be `{x,y}`.

They're used to specify a range of repeat count for a regexp.

```
sed 's/<a\{3,12\}>/<b>/'
```

Would replace the first occurrence of `<` followed by from 3 to 12 `a`s followed by `>` with `<b>`.

On an input like `<a> <aa> <aaaa> <aaaaaaaa>`, it would replace `<aaaa>` with `<b>`.

*Tagged regular expressions* is more commonly refered as *capture groups*.

In BRE, that's with `\(...\)` and with ERE/PCRE with `(...)`. They're used to *capture* the text  that was matched by a regex to use it either as a *back-reference* or in substitutions. Those can also be used for *grouping* (as in `\(foo\)*` for any number of `foo`s).

In:

```
sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2\1/\1\2<\3>\2\1/'
```

We have 3 *tagged expressions* aka *capture groups*, the character (`.` is to match a single character) matched by the first `\(.\)` will be tagged with `1`, and is referred to as `\1` later on in the regexp (so if the first `\(.\)` captured a `x`, `\1` will match on `x` only), and is also called back in the replacement.

On an input like `whatever -+foobar+-`, the regexp will find: `(1:-)(2:+)(3:foobar)(2:+)(1:-)` and the `s` command will replace it with `-+<foobar>+-`.

Standard (POSIX) EREs don't support back references (that `\1` in the regexp above) so the `(...)` there is only for *grouping* (like in `(foo|bar)` or `(foo){1,3}`), though some implementations support it as an extension. The next major release of the POSIX specification will specify the `-E` option for `sed` regexps to use EREs. `\1` in the regexp (back references) will still not be supported, but `\1` in the `s` replacement to expand to what was matched by the corresponding tagged expression will be.

`python`, `perl`, PCRE or compatible regular expressions also let you give arbitrary names to tagged expressions (instead of just `1`, `2`... numbered left to right). See their manual for details.